# How do I add transactions to a recipient-list?

Tags: transactions, esb, mule

I am able to send to a list of dynamic URI's based off of the message's contents.  I have the code place the URI of the destinations in the header key of 'destination.  It can be assumed that the URI coming back is a JMS URI.

An example of the JMS URI is "jms://jmsEndpoint/queue:outbound_queue?connector=jmsConnector"

How do I add transactions to a recipient-list?

```
<flow name="Flow_Name">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="inbound_queue">
        <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" />
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>

    <!-- Code that adds a list of URI's to the header key of 'destination' -->

    <recipient-list expression="destination" evaluator="header" />
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc [clearly states](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Transaction+Management#TransactionManagement-Singleresource%28Local%29Transactions):

> You can send multiple messages using the recipient list router, which will send all messages in the same transaction.

But the XML schema doesn't allow you to specify a transaction configuration for the router. I've checked the source code of org.mule.routing.outbound.ExpressionRecipientList and it should support exceptions just fine.

So my impression is that this is a lack in the XML schema. I may be wrong but I think it's worth opening a [JIRA](http://www.mulesoft.org/jira) and see what the core devs think of the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid I was doing something incorrect.  I read the link you sent and the page regarding [error handling](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Error+Handling).  I was forcing an exception to be thrown, but the message was going to the DLQ, not being rolled back, which I assumed meant I didn't have transactions set up correctly.  Now to dink around with the default error handling.

Comment: OK, just in case I've opened http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-5964 to probe the brains at MuleSoft.